# Error CS0060 using .Net Maui on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

I´ve two classes and the error CS0060 is occurring in the derived class. I've done everything I know but I can't solve it.
Base class

```
namespace cmp.Class
{
    public class cmpComboBox<Cb>
    {
        protected Picker ptComboBox { get; private set; }

        public cmpComboBox(Picker ipelmCombo)
        {
            ptComboBox = ipelmCombo;
        }

        public void setComboBox()
        {
            var vOptions = GetOptions();
            ptComboBox.ItemsSource = vOptions;
            ptComboBox.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Name");
        }

        protected virtual List<Cb> GetOptions()
        {
            return new List<Cb>();
        }
    }
}
```

Derivate Class:

```
namespace cmp.Class
{
    public class QuotationApproved : cmpComboBox<cbOption>
    {
        public QuotationApproved(Picker ptComboBox) : base(ptComboBox)
        {
        }

        protected override List<cbOption> GetOptions()
        {
            return new List<cbOption>
            {
                new cbOption { Name = "Waiting", Value = "0" },
                //new Option { Name = "Approved", Value = "1" },
                //new Option { Name = "Not Approved", Value = "2" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I need fix this error, but I don´t know.

Comment: May I know what is `cbOption`? Can you help add it to your post?

Comment: The error indicates that you may change the Access Modifiers of class  `cbOption` from `internal` to `public`.